# Moving averages with crossfilter.js and dc.js

Tags: crossfilter, dc.js

I would like to use crossfilter.js with dc.js in order to represent moving averages.

Is it possible to calculate moving averages on a set of data or if the data passed in has to already have the averages calculated?

If it's possible, can you please provide a short example.

Thank you,

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're aiming to do. As far as I'm aware it should be perfectly possible to use those libraries as at one point you have to be pushing the data into them, so just calculate the average of n elements and push that instead of pushing the element itself. You'll be behind by roughly n/2 elements against realtime. It would seem to me that as long as you can plot the normal data, then you can plot the moving average.

Answer (score 2):

I would love to be proven wrong but I can't really think of a way to do this in crossfilter.

In the case of a timeseries, the `reduce()` function would be used to perform aggregations across data, grouped by date, as per the highlighted cells below:

[image: Aggregating across fruits]

With a moving average you'd need to perform an operation by looping down the rows:

[image]

Server-side, I wouldn't choose SQL to calculate a moving average on database data; likewise I wouldn't use crossfilter client-side.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still after any help with this, but having just overcome this problem myself, I thought I'd share my solution in case it helps anyone else.

First I declare some pretty standard `reduce` functions to return a simple average, with the addition of two variables to store the averages for t-1 and t-2. I created a 3 period moving average, but if you want a longer one you could easily replace these vars with an array which you `push` and `splice` the data to/from.

```
function movingAveInit(){
  return {
    total: 0,
    count: 0,
    average: 0,
    //These are the two vars for storing previous periods
    avet1: 150000,
    avet2: 150000
  };
}

function movingAveAdd(p,v){
  //'apples' is the property that you're interested in finding the moving average for
  p.total = p.total + v.apples;
  p.count = p.count +1;
  p.avet2 = p.avet1;
  p.avet1 = p.average;
  p.average = p.total/p.count;
  return p;
}

function movingAveRemove(p,v){
  p.total = p.total - v.apples;
  p.count = p.count - 1;
  p.avet2 = p.avet1;
  p.avet1 = p.average;
  p.average = p.total/p.count;
  return p;
}
```

Next call these on your group (the dimension should be whichever time period you are using):

```
var movingAverageGrp = yourDimension.group().reduce(movingAveAdd, movingAveRemove, movingAveInit);
```

Now when you build a chart with this group, add the following to its `valueAccessor()`:

```
yourChart
  .valueAccessor(function (d) { 

        var mAv = ((d.value.avet2 + d.value.avet1 + d.value.average) / 3);
        return mAv; 
   })
```

If you stored previous periods in an array, you can calculate the moving average by using this function instead:

```
.valueAccessor(function (d) { 

    var sum = d.value.yourArray.reduce(function(a, b){ return a + b; });
    var count = d.value.yourArray.length;        
    var mAv = (sum / count);
    return mAv;

    })
```

It's not a particularly beautiful solution, but it seems to work for me.